# How to logout from facebook and google in hybridauth in php

Tags: php, facebook, hybridauth

I am using hybridAuth for social login (facebook,google) in my website. It's working fine, but when a user logs out from my website, it logs him out from my website only, and user still logged in on facebook or google whatever he used to logged in.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('config.php');
    include('hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php');
    if($_SESSION['role'] == 'retailer')
    {
        $url = 'http://mysiteurl.net/demo/index.php';
    } 
    else
    {
        $url = 'http://mysiteurl.net/demo/admin_index.php';
    }

    $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth();
    $hybridauth->logoutAllProviders();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: $url");
    ?>
```

I tried this, but it's not working for me. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Session exists in that person's logged in networks, Person needs to logout from their.

If you want to disconnect connection/data between logged in network and your site you can use following function, but this will works only after the person logged out form that network.

```
public function logout(){
$this->load->library('HybridAuthLib');
$service = $this->hybridauthlib->logoutAllProviders();
}
```